# I am getting a syntax error while defining a function

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error at `%sum2` in line #5:

```
def sum2(l3,x1,x2):
     n1 = (x1.get())
     n2 = (x2.get())
     sum2 = int(n1) + int(n2)
     l3.config(text='Sum of these two numbers is: %d', %sum2)
     return
```

**Link to Error Message**:

[image: Link to error message]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code that you posted you might need to change you line 5 to:

```py
l3.config(text=('Sum of these two numbers is: %d' % sum2))
```

Comment: Yeah, bro I got it after I posted the question but anyways thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `l3.config(text='Sum of these two numbers is: %d', %sum2)`, you will see that you are setting text to equal to **two** things: `'Sum of these two numbers is: %d'` *and* `%sum2`. The actual way of formatting it is like this: `text=('Sum of these two numbers is: %d' %sum2)`

Answer (score 0):

of course, arthursribeiro is right.
For information % is used for taking the modulus of a number by another for example:
10%2 in Python will give an output 0 and for 11%2 will give output 1.
So you had to keep a space between the % and the sum2.